# Image knitted under text in RMarkdown word output

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

I am writing a docx file using RMarkdown and all images I insert, appear under the text that come before each of them. They correct their placement once I adjust it manually in the output document.

[image: wrong way]

I am using the `include_graphics()` function to insert the image, and this is more or less what I have.

````
# Title 1

## Title 2

Some text

```{r}

include_graphics("img.png")

```
````

In the end, I need it to be like this:

[image: right way]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which assumes your image is in the project directory:

````
---
output: word_document
---

# Heading 1

Text


## Heading 2

Text 2

Next paragraph




```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE, out.width="60mm"}

knitr::include_graphics("img.png")

```


Paragraph after image
````

[image]